# .pdf to binary and binary to .pdf

Tags: binary, converters

For a project I need to convert my .pdf, .docx or .jpg file into binary file which is consisted of 0 and 1s. This is the way that the computer saves data on the hard for example. Now I also need to be able to bring back the 0,1 info into the aforementioned file type. Can anyone guide me how to do this? Any scripting language is ok but I prefer python or C

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753899/print-binary-representation-of-file

Comment: The file is already stored in 1s and 0s on disk. There's nothing for you to "convert" - it's already done. If you feel the need to "convert", you're doing something wrong or have a major misunderstanding of computers in general. Why **specifically** do you think you need to do this? What **exactly** are you hoping to accomplish? If you explain that, we might be able to explain why you're trying to do the wrong thing (or how to do it properly if you've misunderstood what's needed).

Answer (score 1):

A pdf docx or jpg file is *already* represented in binary (ones and zeros) when stored on your hard disc.

Hence no conversion is necessary.

If you mean something different (for example, conversion to a form that *displays* on the screen as ones and zeros) then you will need to articulate your question more clearly.

Comment: He/she wants to be able to print it on screen I suppose. It was my first thought too though.

Comment: I am answering the question as he wrote it.  Hopefully he will update the question if he actually means something different.